# Rabbitmq configuration problems (Doesn't read config file)

Tags: rabbitmq

I set: rabbitmq.conf and rabbitmq-env,conf both in /etc/rabbitmq/

rabbit.[{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}].

and in rabbitmq-env.conf

CONFIG_FILE=/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq (also tried with the conf e

but in the log It shows (after rabbit restart):

config file(s) : (none)
and of course no configuration is actually loaded.. Any help? Ideas? `

Comment: Does RabbitMQ show something in logs?

Answer (score 5):

I've got an answer in the rabbitmq google group so I'll share it here:

rabbitmq.conf should be named: rabbitmq.config..

Fixes the problem

Comment: Can you link to the discussion in google groups? Can you accept this answer if this solved your problem?

Comment: Don't forget to also delete the var "CONFIG_FILE" if you set it